# AWS SageMaker: How to set ACL while uploading objects to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

SageMaker ProcessingJob runs in account A, which writes files to a bucket in account B.

The bucket has `Bucket owner preferred` object ownership type set.

Is it possible to configure SageMaker to write to this bucket with `'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'`
as with:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file(file, upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'bucket-owner-full-control'})
```

Seems like there's no option to do this via API:

```
   "ProcessingOutputConfig": { 
      "KmsKeyId": "string",
      "Outputs": [ 
         { 
            "AppManaged": boolean,
            "FeatureStoreOutput": { 
               "FeatureGroupName": "string"
            },
            "OutputName": "string",
            "S3Output": { 
               "LocalPath": "string",
               "S3UploadMode": "string",
               "S3Uri": "string"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing Jobs cannot pass `ExtraArgs={'ACL':'bucket-owner-full-control'})` for `S3Output`.

You could look at making the upload in the script running in the Processing Job yourself.